# How can I import jDatePicker into a BlueJ Java program?

Tags: java, bluej

I'm trying to use the jDatePicker tool from here: sourceforge.net/projects/jdatepicker/files/latest/download and I've placed the .jar file in C:\Program Files (x86)\BlueJ\lib\userlib and it's been recognised in the BlueJ preferences but I have no idea how to actually use it in my project. I've tried all sorts of import commands but it's not picking it up. Any ideas?

Update: OK, i've now got it to compile, but the applet doesn't run, BlueJ just says "Applet not initialised":

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.*;
import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.impl.*;
import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.util.*;

public class Task1 extends java.applet.Applet implements ActionListener
{
    public void init()
{
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(200,240);
    JButton btnConfirm=new JButton("Confirm"); //initalises the button
    btnConfirm.setBounds(15,2,100,20);
    add(btnConfirm); //paints it on the screen
    btnConfirm.addActionListener(this); 

    TextField text = new TextField(20);
    text.setBounds(5,24,185,20);
    add(text);

    UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
    JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model);
    JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel);
    datePicker.setBounds(50,80,185,20);
    add(datePicker);

}
/* Use the method actionPerformed to trap the event button clicked */ 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{ 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ALERT MESSAGE","TITLE",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
}
```

Comment: `import org.jdatepicker.JDatePicker;` But the jar file needs to be present in the classpath.

Comment: OK, well blueJ appears to have recognised that, but when I come to following this tutorial http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/how-to-use-jdatepicker-to-display-calendar-component, the following lines don't work as it says it can't find the symbol for these 3 classes:
        UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
        JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model);
        JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel); Even when trying import org.jdatepicker.*

Comment: These classes are in other packages, you need to import the classes in these packages as well. Check my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import other classes in your Java files, you need to add an import statement with the full qualified name of the class (The file name with the package).

To import the `JDatePicker` class, you need to add:

```
import org.jdatepicker.JDatePicker;
```

If you want to import all the classes in a package, you can use `*`:

```
import org.jdatepicker.*;
```

The classes must be present in the Classpath. As you are adding the JAR file in the `BlueJ\lib\userlib`  folder, this should be enough to import the classes correctly.

You may need to import other classes in other packages like:

```
import org.jdatepicker.impl.*;
import org.jdatepicker.util.*;
```

Import your required classes or packages as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell java where to find the library. You do this by adding the location, where you put the library to your classpath.

Usually your IDE supports you in this process by providing a GUI to do this.
For BlueJ, take a look here: http://www.bluej.org/faq.html#faq_How_do_I_use_custom_class_libraries__JARs__